# How to copy files from Linux to Windows with RDP (Vinagre)?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, samba, file-transfer, amazon-ec2

I'm able to log in to my `EC2` instance with `Vinagre` but can't figure out how to copy files from my (Ubuntu 12.04) machine to that (Windows Server 2008) slice.

Some googling yielded [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/rdesktop-remote-desktop-xp-connection-308395/) which recommends `rdesktop -u Administrator -r disk:linux=. ec2-23-22-57-87.compute-1.amazon.com` however that causes the following error.

```
Autoselected keyboard map en-us
ERROR: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

Looking [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1044302) people suggest shutting off `avahi daemon` (doesn't work) or this superuser question [Why does remote desktop not work for me by computer name, and only by IP?](https://superuser.com/questions/52109/why-does-remote-desktop-not-work-for-me-by-computer-name-and-only-by-ip) which doesn't work for me either.

How do I copy files from Ubuntu to Windows with `RDP`?

Comment: Just a clarification : is it supposed to look like this `disk:linux=. ec2-23-22-57-87.compute-1.amazon.com`.  The '.' after = looks out of place.

Comment: @GauravJoseph Actually I agree with you, that does look weird. But I forget now because it's been so long.

Comment: Oooh dammit didn't check the date earlier... Gaaah!

Comment: the `.` is fine.  it just means the current working directory will be shared