# Remoting into wrong user, computerName.user

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I'm trying to remote into my work computer. Let's say that the user name is Bob, and that the computer name is Comp1.

I'm connecting just fine, logging in using my regular credentials, but it seems like instead of logging me into my user account, Bob, it's creating me a new one, Bob.Comp1.

I want to be logged into Bob. It's logging me into Bob.Comp1, which doesn't have any of my stuff on it.

What's going on?

Comment: Try with ip or here have a look at this discussion http://superuser.com/questions/52109/why-does-remote-desktop-not-work-for-me-by-computer-name-and-only-by-ip which may get you with some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is comp1 integrated in a windows domain?
Perhaps you loggin with the domain user and normally you are working with a local user.

Comment: It is a domained user. When I log into the physical computer now (non-remote), it gives me an option to log into Comp1\Bob or DOMAIN\Bob. I want to log into DOMAIN\Bob via remote desktop.

Comment: I got it. All you need to do evidently is specify DOMAIN\Bob as your user name. Doh!

Thanks man!

Comment: I see a question and a self-reflection statement.  I am having trouble understanding how this answers the author's question.